# Require a Text Field with height adjusted to the text's font size without any padding at the top and bottom

Tags: flutter, textfield

I require a text field with a container as parent widget that specifies a width but not a height. The height of the text field should be determined by the given font size, and there should be no padding added above or below the text content.

Example:

[This is actual text field I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxFDM.jpg)

This is my required text field. If we set height to container as 20, it will render like below, but I want without setting height and without top & bottom padding
[Required text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj4x1.jpg)

Added the code for the reference,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            child: TextField(
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
              autofocus: true,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.blue),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.green),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                ),
              ),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 13,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  height: 1,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I attempted to produce the desired output, but what I received matched the image mentioned earlier as the actual result.

Comment: You can give height for your container view.             height: 30,

Comment: try using padding.

Comment: @ChiragSondagar No I want the required output without giving height to the container, wants to remove the padding above and below the text content

Comment: @BalajiR Why don't need to use hight? I think you need a flexible view as per content right?

Comment: @ChiragSondagar, I don't want to use height, it must be automatically taken based on font size. Below example is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flexible height of container view then you can you like this way.

```
Container(
        height: searchByStopPointControl.text.length > 50 ? null :  30,
        child: TextField(
          maxLines: null,
          controller: searchByStopPointControl,
          onChanged: (value){
            setState(() {});
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0), // Adjust the vertical padding as needed
            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.blue),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.green),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
            ),
          ),
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              height: 1,
              // decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```